# I'm not able to change keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm currently running lubuntu 14.4. which I re-installed recently after using 15.10 (the computer kept shutting down due to overheating and the system stopped working properly). 
Now, I'm having trouble when changing keyboard input (which I didn't have when running 14.04 before). Namely, I use Croatian or Serbian (Cyrillic) as well as English. I added the languages in iBus, but I can't switch between them (the keyboard shortcut doesn't work, nor does manually selecting a language). The only way to choose an input (other than the default) is to delete all the inputs besides the one I need and then reboot. Also, whichever input is selected, the icon in Task Bar shows "US". 
Any suggestions on how to fix the bug (I even tried re-installing the system completely, same thing happened)?

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the keyboard alyout chosen at installation doesn't always map to the user's keyboard settings. I use the following steps to change from US to GB layout:

1. Right-click the 'US' icon in the taskbar, and select ‘”Keyboard Layout Handler” Settings’.
2. The ‘Keyboard Layout Handler’ window will be displayed, the left hand side of the window will be greyed out. Deselect ‘Keep system layouts’ by clearing the adjacent check box. This will enable input on the left hand side of the window.
3. In the ‘Keyboard Layouts’ section, click the ‘+ Add’ button, and select the correct option from the ‘Add Keyboard Layout’ screen. Click ‘OK’. The entry should now appear in the ‘Keyboard Layouts’ section.
4. Highlight the ‘US’ entry in the ‘Keyboard Layouts’ section by clicking it once, and click the ‘- Remove’ button. The selected option should be the only remaining entry in the list, and the icon in the bottom panel will now display the initials for this layout setting. Click the ‘Close’ button.

I hope they work for the Cyrillic layout.

Comment: On Lubuntu:

1. On right-click I dont have "Keyboard Layout Handler", I have: Preferences (iBus), About, Restart (cause display to freeze), Quit.

Answer (score 1):

In case when you want to use IBus that helped  me:

- Right-click the 'US' icon in the taskbar, and select ‘”Keyboard Layout Handler” Settings
- **Select** ‘Keep system layouts’ by setting up the adjacent check box.
- Launch language support and select IBus as input method.
- Log out and log in.
- In the IBus settings window on third tab **deselect** ‘Keep system layouts’.